# intersection of two complex equations

Tags: complex-numbers

I think the question I'm stuck on is quite simple but for some reason I just can't see how to do it.

I'm told that the points A and B represent the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ respectively. The angle $AOB = 90^{\circ}$ and $OA = OB$ ( I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure how to draw a diagram in Latex but you can find it in the link below).

I'm asked to prove that $z_2 = \mathbf{i}z_1$ which I can do.

I am also told that $L_1$ is the locus of points satisfying:

$ \begin{vmatrix} z - z_2 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} z - z_1 \end{vmatrix}$

and that $L_2$ is the locus of points satisfying:

$ \arg(z - z_2) =  arg(z_1) $

I think that $L_1$ is a line going through the origin and is the perpendicular bisector of the points $A$ and $B$ and I think that $L_2$ is a half line starting at B parallel to $OA$.

What I'm struggling with is finding the complex number, in terms of $z_1$, which represents the point of intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$.

The full question is [here](http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-MFP2-W-QP-JUN07.PDF) question 5, part (c).

I think it's something to do with the fact that both $L_1$ and $L_2$ have $z - z_2$ in them and that you know $z_2 = \mathbf{i}z_1$ but I'm not too sure how to go about it.

Thank you :)

Comment: You should include the full question here. A link to the larger problem for clarification is good, but a reader shouldn't have to link to view the question itself.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer ahh okay, sorry and thank you :) I hope that's a little better.